# Why would an AutoMapperExtension behave differently from a direct implementation?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have defined the following mapping within `RegisterMappings()` of `AutoMapperConfig`:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Member, PhotoViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Show, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ShowPhoto))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PhotoValueViewModel>(src));
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Member, PhotoValueViewModel>();
```

This mapping maps two properties of a `PhotoViewModel`. First it maps the `Show` property based off of `src.ShowPhoto`, and then it maps a `PhotoValueViewModel` into the `Value` property.

The mapping works! Unfortunately, I have many objects that require a similar mapping. So, I tried abstracting some of the implementation into an AutoMapperExtension method. The method looks like this:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ApplyPropertyMapping<TSource, TDestination>
        (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> iMappingExpression, Expression<Func<TSource, bool?>> show, Expression<Func<TSource, object>> value)
        where TDestination : PropertyViewModel
    {
        iMappingExpression
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Show, opt => opt.MapFrom(show))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(value));
        return iMappingExpression;
    }
```

I'd expect this extension method to allow me to define the original mapping as:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Member, PhotoViewModel>()
    .ApplyPropertyMapping(src => src.ShowPhoto, src => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PhotoValueViewModel>(src));
```

But it doesn't work! Now calls to `Mapper.Map<Member, PhotoViewModel>(MemberObject, PhotoViewModelObject)` set the `PhotoViewModelObject.Value` property to null.

What is causing the difference?

The definitions of some of these objects are:

```
public class Member
{
    /**Irrelevant Properties Not Shown**/
    public Guid? PhotoID { get; set; }
    public string PhotoFileName { get; set; }
    public bool? ShowPhoto { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyViewModel
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public bool? Show { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoViewModel : PropertyViewModel
{
    public PhotoValueViewModel Value { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoValueViewModel
{
    public Guid? PhotoID { get; set; }
    public string PhotoFileName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl {get {return Utils.GeneratePhotoUrl(PhotoID); } }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of `Member`, `PhotoViewModel`, and `PhotoValueViewModel`?

Comment: I have edited question to include their definitions.

Comment: You should have a `ShowPhoto` property in the `Member` class? What is its type? can you add it?

Comment: You're right, there *is* a `ShowPhoto` property. I made a mistake by not adding it in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PhotoViewModel` class contains two properties with the name `Value`, one of them is defined in `PropertyViewModel` and is of type `object`. And the other one is defined in `PhotoViewModel` and is of type `PhotoValueViewModel` (this is basically [hiding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the other property, you should be getting a warning about this from Visual Studio).

Inside your extension method you are referencing `PropertyViewModel.Value` which is of type `object`

This is because the `TDestination` type is declared in this method to be assignable from `PropertyViewModel` (via `where TDestination : PropertyViewModel`).

Your extension method is working correctly, it is changing the value of that property (`PropertyViewModel.Value`).

Your original mapping (without the extension method) is mapping the value to `PhotoViewModel.Value` which is of type `PhotoValueViewModel`.

You can use Visual Studio debugger to watch both `PropertyViewModel.Value` and `PhotoViewModel.Value` in both cases (with or without the extension method).

Comment: You're absolutely right! I was treating the property hiding like an override. Removing `public PhotoValueViewModel Value { get; set; }` from the `PhotoViewModel` solved the problem.

Thank you for your help!